# CSS Border around my content

Tags: html, css

So, I have a very, very simple content page. For some reason, it has a border all the way around my content.

```
.container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.container iframe {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
#navbar-2 {
height: 0px; 
width: 100%;
background: #2B2B2B;
}
.container input {
width: 100px;
height: 25px;
}
.body {
background-color: #F1F1F1;
color: #FC5E5E;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
```

and here is my HTML.

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<small>Please note that only links that will be looked at are *<b>SoundCloud and Youtube</b>.*        </small><br>
<small>For the E-Mail form you must submit your ACTUAL email or the request will not send, For Song URL you need to submit a valid You-Tube link or SoundCloud link in order for it to submit.    </small><br>
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<small><p><b>Twitch Name:</b></small><br> <input type="text" name="yourname" /><br>
<small><b>Song Name:</b></small><br> <input type="text" name="subject" /><br>
<small><b>E-mail:</b></small><br> <input type="text" name="email" /><br>
<small><b>Song URL:</b></small><br> <input type="text" name="website"></p>
<small><p><b>Lifestory:</b></small><br />
<textarea name="comments" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send it!"></p>
<p> </p>
</form>
</center>
<div id="navbar-2"></div>
<iframe src="" frameBorder="0">Browser not compatible.    </iframe>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the border in the image :

[image]

It looks like it is about 5PX and it's not from the iframe.

Comment: Those `<b>`s should be `<label>`s. See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Comment: Assuming you're using HTML5, you're using `<small>` inappropriately (i.e. contrary to its semantics). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small

Comment: @danielnixon lol, thank you edited those - I am actually really just looking to get the border issue fixed though as this is not a serious project.

Comment: It looks like there may be some padding on the body. [Also the center tag has been depreciated.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

Comment: @apaul34208 but I did not asign a padding anywhere? So I am not sure why it would be there also when I set the padding to `padding: 0px;` nothing happens.

Comment: Your `<html>` element should have a `lang` attribute. See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H57.html

Comment: Try selecting the body element not a class named body. `.body` should be `body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the days of the web without CSS, HTML came pre-styled. Some of this styling included padding around the entire document.

What you are looking for is called a [reset stylesheet](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/).

> A CSS Reset (or “Reset CSS”) is a short, often compressed (minified)
>   set of CSS rules that resets the styling of all HTML elements to a
>   consistent baseline.

You can find them from various sources around the web, [like this one](http://www.cssreset.com/), and you just simply link to it before your other styles.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
```

Hope this helps!